# GCC: How to assemble a file in one command?

Tags: gcc, assembly

It's easy to compile C source code into an executable: `gcc hello.c -o hello`. In contrast, this is how I am currently turning an assembly program into an executable:

```
cpp -P hello.S > hello.s  # Run preprocessor.
as hello.s -o hello.o  # Assemble.
ld hello.o -o hello  # Link.
```

Is there a way to do all of this using one command?

The OS is Debian 10.1 Buster running on a mipsel (32-bit MIPS little endian) machine.

For reference, this is `hello.S`, a MIPS assembly program that requires the use of the C preprocessor:

```
#include <regdef.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

.data
    mymsg: .asciiz "Hello\n"

.text
    .global __start

__start:
    li a0, 1
    la a1, mymsg
    li a2, 6
    li v0, SYS_write
    syscall
    li a0, 1
    li v0, SYS_exit
    syscall
```

Answer (score 1):

**`gcc -static -nostdlib hello.S`** runs it through CPP, then assembles it and links *just* that `.o`, no CRT start files and no libraries, not even `libgcc.a`.

`-nostdlib` is like `-nostartfiles` but leaves out libraries as well as CRT startup code.  If I understand the docs correctly, `-nostdlib` is a combination of `-nodefaultlibs -nostartfiles`.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

Modern Linux distros usually configure gcc with the default being `-pie -fPIE`.  Using `-static` disables that (because PIE is a hack that uses an ELF "shared object" as an executable).  ([32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux)).  Leaving `-fPIE` on doesn't matter if there are no `.c` or `.cpp` inputs, only assembler; it's a code-gen option.

Comment: `gcc -static -nostdlib hello.S` produces an executable, but running the executable (`./a.out`) prints `Bus error` with an exit code of 138.

Comment: @Flux: So use a `strace ./a.out` and/or a debugger to find out what's wrong with your executable.  Like maybe your `.data` section isn't aligned?  Are you saying this executable is different from what you get by running `gcc -c hello.S` then `ld` manually?  Use `gcc ... -v` to show what commands it ran.

Answer (score -1):

From [the overal options part](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html) of [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/index.html):

> `file.S`
>   `file.sx`
>
> Assembler code that must be preprocessed.

So the support for preprocessing, assembling and linking such source file is already supported.

Comment: `gcc hello.S` results in an error `(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to \`main'` `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`. Running `gcc hello.S -nostdlib` produces an executable, but running the executable prints garbage. My system's architecture is 32-bit MIPS in little endian mode.

Comment: @Flux Try `-nostdlib -nostartfiles`.

Comment: @fuz The resulting executable still prints garbage.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  I was briefly fooled too into thinking just `gcc hello.S` would be the answer, but notice the `ld` command line that omits any libraries or CRT start files.  That's the key part of the question.

Comment: @Flux: Are you sure Linux/ELF on MIPS still prepends symbols with a leading `_`?  i.e. are you sure the C symbol `_start` really has the asm name `__start`?  If your program is printing garbage, have you tried using a debugger?  It sounds very weird that `-nostdlib` compiles without complaint but then doesn't work the same as manually running `ld`.  Unless Linux/MIPS lets non-PIE-compatible code link into a PIE executable and then fail at runtime...  Or whatever OS you have